# how to initialize a character array from string with special hex values in between

Tags: c, gcc

I get an "initilizer is not computable at load time" error in gcc-89 with the first line of code. In 99 it seemed ok. 
What is the difference in the two lines below?

```
const unsigned char BYTES[] = {0x02, "FFFEU", 0x0C, "FFFFFFFF"};
const unsigned char BYTES[] = {0x02, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x45, 0x55, 0x0C, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46};
```

The second line works fine but it is too complicated to look up every char in an ASCII table.

Comment: thus these initializations wouldn't be equivalent anyway.

Comment: Use `const unsigned char BYTES[] = "\002FFFEU\014FFFFFFFF";`. There is no difference, both are wrong.

Comment: Specifically, `"FFFEU"` is not a `char`, it's a pointer to `char`

Comment: Just to be sure: are you really interested in the difference or do you want to know how to initialize a character array from string with those special hex values in between?

Comment: @grek40 you described precisely, what I would like to do!

Comment: @Stefatronik then you asked the wrong question... your question is so far from your desired result that it can't even be edited into the right question without making existing answers obsolete -> bad thing!

Comment: However, it's probably best to add your requirement to the question in a sensible way so the original question stays visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are two ways to initialize an array of constant characters: (1) initialize with an initializer list of character values

```
const char bytes1[] = { 'A', 65, 0x41, 0101, 0 }; // results in a zero terminated string "AAAA"
```

Here, each value is a single character value in different code representations.

(2) initialize with a string literal which can optionally be enclosed in braces

```
const char bytes2[] = "AAAA";
const char bytes3[] = { "AAAA" };
```

Those two are equivalent, both result in the same zero terminated string. However, just that the `{ "AAAA" }` syntax is valid doesn't mean that any combination with a comma and more values would be valid.

```
// ALL of the following are INVALID
const char bytes4[] = { "AAA", 'A' };
const char bytes5[] = { 'A', "AAA" };
const char bytes6[] = { "AA", "AA" };
```

Now there is a second topic involved in your question: hexadecimal values within a character sequence / string literal. As seen above, `'A'` can be represented as decimal `65` in ascii and the 65 can be presented decimal, octal, hexadecimal, ...

Utilizing single character values, this could look as follows (remember `bytes1`):

```
const char bytes7[] = { '\x41', 'A', '\101', 'A', 0 };
```

There is a problem with the direct translation into a string literal:

```
// The following is INVALID
const char bytes8[] = "\x41A\101A";
```

Writing the same as string literal is not directly possible, because in `"\x41A"`, the `A` will be considered part of the hexadecimal sequence instead of a separate character that follows the hexadecimal. The resulting value will be out of range for a character type. This can be solved by concatenation of string literals: `"\x41" "A"` - just two literals next to each other, without any non-whitespace character in between.

```
// The following is VALID
const char bytes9[] = "\x41" "A\101A";
```

So the same principle can be applied to your case:

```
// VALID
const unsigned char BYTES[] = { "\x02" "FFFEU\x0C" "FFFFFFFF" };
```

The leading `0` in the hex sequences are not really necessary and as said above, the braces are also optional.

Comment: Thanks this 1. solved my problem 2. was a great explanation

Answer (score 0):

case 1:

```
const unsigned char BYTES[] = {0x02, "FFFEU", 0x0C, "FFFFFFFF"};
```

here BYTES is a `const char array` i.e you can store no of characters(int are allowed) but how you can  store `strings`("FFFEU"  <-- see the double quotations ) into this, it should be `0xFFFEU` or `'FFFEU'`

modify as

```
const unsigned char BYTES[] = {0x02, 0xFFFEU, 0x0C, 0xFFFFFFFF};
```

but again you can't store such `big data(0xFFFEU)` in `1 byte memory`, compiler may not give `error`, but it will `overwrite` other bytes,  so you will not get expected result.

Comment: My aim is to store the ascii codes of "FFFEU" -> 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x45, 0x55, not as a string (don't want the trailing \0) but I can't write the whole command as text because of the special characters 0x02 or 0x0c